# Erro ao acessar JSON com Ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Estou recebendo um *JSON* que criei com *PHP* como descrito a baixo, porém, quando tento acessar as propriedades desse *JSON* ele sempre me retorna *undefined*.

Fiz esses arquivos teste ai pra demonstrar como estou fazendo.

Se eu der um `console.log` no data, ele me retorna o *JSON* certinho

Alguém consegue ajudar?

**Função *PHP* que me retorna o *JSON*:**

```
function listaAluno(){

    $conn = Conexao::pegaConexao();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from tab_sys_student");
    $stmt->execute();
    $dados['data'] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($dados);
}
```

**Função *JS* que acessa o *JSON*:**

```
function listaCurso(){
    alert('listou');
    $.ajax({
        url: "restrict/checkUser.php",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        dataType : 'json' ,/*adiciona o tipo de retorno*/
        error: function(){
            alert('Erro ao Tentar ação.');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.crs_id);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Como está o arquivo checkUser.php?

Comment: É essa função php ai

Comment: Vc quer que retorne apenas 1 registro do banco ou todos?

Comment: Quero  Todo o banco.

Comment: Se for todos, irá retornar vários `data.crs_id`... qual deles vc quer capturar em específico ou quer capturar todos?

Comment: Eu preciso de todos.

Comment: Fiz uma alteração na minha resposta, mas veja se alguma das duas respostas lhe atende.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está recebendo um *JSON Array*, por isso não é possível acessar a propriedade `crs_id` diretamente, para isso é necessário utilizar um laço de repetição ou utilizar o índice:

**Exemplo com Índice:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "restrict/checkUser.php",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType : 'json' ,/*adiciona o tipo de retorno*/
    error: function(){
        alert('Erro ao Tentar ação.');
    },
    success: function (result) {
        alert('listou');

        console.log(result.data[0].crs_id);
        console.log(result.data[1].crs_id);
        console.log(result.data[2].crs_id);
        console.log(result.data[3].crs_id);
    }
});
```

**Exemplo com laço de repetição:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "restrict/checkUser.php",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType : 'json' ,/*adiciona o tipo de retorno*/
    error: function(){
        alert('Erro ao Tentar ação.');
    },
    success: function (result) {
        alert('listou');

        for (let d of result.data) { // Ou "(let d of result)"
            console.log(d.crs_id);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Como enviar esse json sem ser array?

Comment: Você deve utilizar o `echo json_encode( $stmt->fetch() );`, porém só irá retornar **um** registro, apenas.